# Split monomorphism and split epimorphisms of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, banach-spaces

Consider the category **Ban** of Banach spaces with linear contractions. I want to find a characterization of the split monomorphisms and of the split epimorphisms in this category, however I couldn't make much progress.

I know that every split monomorphism is a monomorphism in any category and in **Ban** these are precisely the injective morphisms, but it seems that not any injective linear contraction is also a split monomorphism. In fact, I am kind of confused. Let $f:X\to Y$ be an injective linear contraction. Then, we can show that it has a linear left inverse, call it $g:Y\to X$. Now we have $1_X=g\circ f$, which implies that $1=||g\circ f||\le ||g||\cdot ||f||\le ||g||$. I guess that this means that $g$ must have norm $1$ in order for it to be a  contraction. But I don't know what other condition I should impose on $f$ so that such a $g$ exists.

Similarly, every split epimorphism is an epimorphism, so this means that every split epimorphism in **Ban** has a dense image, but again I don't think the converse holds and I don't know how to find what other properties I should add.

Comment: Even if you just require $f$ to a have *bounded* left inverse, this already implies $f$ is bounded below, or equivalently the range of $f$ is closed. The existence of such a $g$ also implies then that $f(X)$ must be complemented in $Y$, as $\mathrm{ker}(g)$ is such a complement. This is another very strong condition. For example, if I remember correctly $c_0$ is *not* complemented in $l^\infty$.

Comment: In your specific example, I think the most can be said is that $f$ is a split monomorphism iff it is an isometric embedding and that its range is complemented in $Y$ and admits a norm 1 projection (from $Y$ to the range of $f$).

Comment: By the same argument, split epimorphisms are exactly norm 1 projections onto closed subspaces followed by isometric isomorphisms.

Comment: If you allow your category to contain all bounded linear maps, similar arguments show that split monomorphisms are embeddings onto closed, complemented subspaces; and split epimorphisms are projections onto closed subspaces followed by bounded isomorphisms.

Comment: @DavidGao interesting, I think that what you said makes sense. What I read for sure is that in this category **Ban** that I mentioned the isomorphisms are the isometric bijections that are also linear contractions. It seems that your characterizations of split monomorphisms and split epimorphisms implies this, right?

Comment: Yes, isomorphisms in **Ban** are isometric linear bijections. You can certainly use my characterization of split monomorphisms and epimorphisms to prove this, as an isometric embedding that is also a norm 1 projection (and therefore surjective) is necessarily an isometric linear bijection, though it’s easier to just prove that directly.

Comment: @DavidGao How would you get that one directly? I cannot see a quick argument.

Comment: Let $f$ be an isomorphism in **Ban**. Then it admits an inverse $g$. Since $f \circ g = Id$ and $g \circ f = Id$, $f$ is a bijection. We also have both $f$ and $g$ are contractions, so $||x|| \geq ||f(x)|| \geq ||g(f(x))|| = ||x||$, so $||x|| = ||f(x)||$ and $f$ is isometric. Conversely, if $f$ is an isometric linear bijection, its set-theoretic inverse is easily seen to be isometric and linear as well, so its set-theoretic inverse is in **Ban** and so $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @DavidGao thank you very much, you really helped me a lot with these questions. If you decide to turn your comments into an answer I will be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, this is my comments turned into an answer, with somewhat more details added:

$f$ is a split monomorphism iff it is an isometric embedding and that its range is complemented in $Y$ and admits a norm 1 projection (from $Y$ to the range of $f$). Indeed, if $f$ is a split monomorphism, then there exists a linear contraction $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f = Id_X$. Then $||x|| \geq ||f(x)|| \geq ||g(f(x))|| = ||x||$, so $||x|| = ||f(x)||$ and $f$ is an isometric embedding. (This argument also shows that in **Ban**, isomorphisms are isometric linear bijections.) $f \circ g$ then is a norm 1 projection from $Y$ onto the range of $f$ and the range is complemented by $\mathrm{ker}(g)$ in $Y$. Conversely, if $f$ is a linear embedding and there is a norm 1 projection $P$ from $Y$ onto the range of $f$, then we may let $g = f^{-1} \circ P$, which one can show is a linear contraction and that $g \circ f = Id_X$, so $f$ is a split monomorphism.

By similar arguments, split epimorphisms are exactly norm 1 projections onto closed subspaces followed by isometric isomorphisms. Furthermore, if you allow your category to contain all bounded linear maps, similar arguments show that split monomorphisms are embeddings onto closed, complemented subspaces; and split epimorphisms are projections onto closed subspaces followed by bounded isomorphisms. (These require the use of the open mapping theorem.)

Comment: sorry for bothering you with another question, but for the split epimorphisms is this the result you had in mind: a linear contraction $f:X\to Y$ between the Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ is a split epimorphism if and only if there exists a closed subspace $Z$ of $X$ and a bijective linear isometry $g:Z\to Y$ such that $f=g\circ P$, where $P:X\to Z$ is the projection operator? I want to make sure I got it right.

Comment: @math_is_hard $P$ has to a projection operator of norm 1, which isn't always the case for projections. Also, since you are dealing with general Banach spaces, there isn't a canonical projection operator, so "the" projection operator is not an accurate thing to say. Other than that, you are correct. (There are examples where a closed subspace of a Banach space is complemented but no projection of norm 1 exists. For example, see Theorem 6.2 in this survey: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110171v1.pdf )

Comment: thank you for the clarifications! Yes, I realize now that there is no canonical projection in this case, I had Hilbert spaces in mind for some reasons.